# Magento 2: How to deploy an image file on production site?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, static-content-deploy, deployment

We changed one image file at this location and now we want to deploy it on live:

`app/design/frontend/theme/theme1/web/images/sample.jpg`

We learned that the only way to deploy static files in production is:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_AU -f`

This command takes time to complete and we need to take the site down for around 30 minutes just to update production. This isn't useful for us.

**Do you have any recommendation to optimize the process of updating small static files?**

Comment: You can try to replace the image in both pub and theme folder. The quick reflection of such data is from pub folder. And when the change has reflected you can run the deployment command by the time users will not feel any change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@LAW, is correct. For the current version of Magento 2, it is impossible to deploy selected static files. What we do is we keep our Magento 2 websites's mode to `developer`. If you are in `production` mode, the fastest route is to manually replace or update the file in your pub/static files. In your question, you deploy in en_AU, so path should be similar below:

`pub/static/frontend/theme/theme1/en_AU/images/sample.jpg`